# Updateprogess image is not ending or disappearing or vanishing or hiding after Response.Redirect is called

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, hide, response.redirect, updateprogress

I have an updateprogress bar, displaying a text "loading". After I hit a imagebutton (I am using it for downloading a file) inside my update panel, with a click event, It calls click function , and click function is like below. The download screen of open, save, close cames. And updateprogress bar displays "loading". But after downloading the file, this "loading" text is not disappearing. What should i do to make it disappear ?

```
protected void downloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/temporary_reports/" + "x_report" + "_" + numberOfTicks + ".xls");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that you can also give imageurl to hyperlinks, and that solves the problem.